# Doxygen documentation for enum class in a seperate header

Tags: doxygen

I was trying to add documentation for an enum class which resides in its own header file. Below is what I have done so far

```
/**
@file
*/
namespace foo {

/**
@brief blablabla
*/
enum class MyEnum{
    /**
     This is ENUM_A
    */
    ENUM_A,
    /**
     This is ENUM_B
    */
    ENUM_B,
    /**
     This is ENUM_C
    */
    ENUM_C
};
}
```

For some reason, the generated doc shows these 3 enum members in the list, but when I click them, it doesn't generate the page that has their own description. However this worked when I put this enum class in another class.
Could any one help me to spot what I have been missing? Thanks.

Comment: In the supplied fragment the file is documented (with an empty string) in the first comment block, but the namespace itself is not documented.For further details see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/docblocks.html):

> To document a member of a C++ class, you must also document the class
>   itself. The same holds for namespaces. To document a global C
>   function, typedef, enum or preprocessor definition you must first
>   document the file that contains it (usually this will be a header
>   file, because that file contains the information that is exported to
>   other source files).

So if you document your `foo` namespace, everything works fine:

```
/**
@brief Namespace foo
*/
namespace foo {

/**
@brief My enum
*/
enum class MyEnum{
    /**
     This is ENUM_A
    */
    ENUM_A,
    /**
     This is ENUM_B
    */
    ENUM_B,
    /**
     This is ENUM_C
    */
    ENUM_C
};
}
```

First click on Namespace, then `foo` and then your enum documentation is available.

**UPDATE**

---

As @albert pointed out, there is an alternative way. According to the [Doxygen documentation](https://www.star.bnl.gov/public/comp/sofi/doxygen/config.html#cfg_extract_all),

> If the `EXTRACT_ALL` tag is set to `YES` doxygen will assume all
>   entities in documentation are documented, even if no documentation was
>   available. Private class members and static file members will be
>   hidden unless the `EXTRACT_PRIVATE` and `EXTRACT_STATIC` tags are set
>   to `YES`

This is a nice option if you have many such scenarios in your codebase.

Comment: Small addition the original first comment block, in the question, documents the file and thus the ```namespace``` is not documented. Either document the ```namespace`` as written bu @bobmorane or set ```EXTRACT_ALL``` in the doxygen configuration file (```Doxyfile```) to ```YES```.